# Can X̄ₙ represent the expected value of the nth X?

Tags: probability

Suppose we draw a sample of n individuals – X₁, X₂...Xₙ – each a random variable. Can we use X̄ₙ to represent the expected value of the nth X, or can this notation only be used to represent the sample mean of n individuals?

Comment: The latter: $\bar{X}_n$ represents the sample mean of a sample of $n$ individuals. The expected value of the $n$-th $X$ would be $\mu$ if the data are iid.

Comment: It is best to explain whatever notation you use, rather than expecting your readers to interpret it in the way you intended, *especially* when you're aware of multiple reasonable interpretations!